# Pandas dropna and filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe, called "fechadas":

```
print(fechadas)

              CNPJ                                         Favorecido
0    9574957000116                             ccs construtora eireli   
1   73780215000146         d & m empreiteira de projetos e obras ltda   
2   21592015000166                        f t r construtora ltda - me   
3                                                                       
4                                                                       
5   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
6   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
7   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
8   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
9   17483741000173                      comercial tocantins ltda - me   
10                                                                      
11  17483741000173                      comercial tocantins ltda - me   
12
```

I want to take out the rows where "Favorecido" is empty, so I'm using this code:

```
fechadas=fechadas.dropna(subset=["Favorecido"],axis=0)
fechadas=fechadas.loc[((fechadas['Favorecido'] != "") | (fechadas['Favorecido'] != " ")]
fechadas=fechadas.loc[(len(fechadas['Favorecido']) != 0) | (fechadas['Favorecido'] != True)]
```

However, when I print fechadas it just looks exactly the same:

```
              CNPJ                                         Favorecido  \
0    9574957000116                             ccs construtora eireli   
1   73780215000146         d & m empreiteira de projetos e obras ltda   
2   21592015000166                        f t r construtora ltda - me   
3                                                                       
4                                                                       
5   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
6   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
7   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
8   20739399000134      four business desenvolvimento e servicos ltda   
9   17483741000173                      comercial tocantins ltda - me   
10                                                                      
11  17483741000173                      comercial tocantins ltda - me   
12
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest change second condition with [`Series.str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for remove possible more spaces:

```
fechadas=fechadas[(fechadas['Favorecido'].str.strip() != "")]
```

If not working, check how looks problematic values:

```
print (df.loc[[3,4,10,12], 'Favorecido'].tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest change second condition to:
use " = " instead of "!="

Comment: OP need `I want to take out the rows where "Favorecido" is empty, so I'm using this code:`